# Javascript is messing up formatting elsewhere

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I've added some script to my code and it's messing up formatting elsewhere in my doc. I thought maybe it had to do with where I was including it and I read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/436411/where-is-the-best-place-to-put-script-tags-in-html-markup) and tried to add async or defer but it didn't make a difference. Specifically, it's adding a block of space on the right side of my "aboutus5" div and then my footer is all squished to the left. As soon as I remove the code, the formatting goes back to normal. So I'm still not sure if it's the placement of the code or maybe just bad code I have elsewhere that is only now being affected.

Any suggestions would be much appreciated!!

Here's the specific code that's screwing things up:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js" defer></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

And here's all of the code (I know it's really bad... this is my first go at building a website):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js" defer></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<title>Budget Line of Business</title>
<style>
h1 {font-family: 'Footlight MT Light', 'Garamond';
       font-size: 100px; color:#FF3B3F; font-weight: bold; margin: 0 }
h2 {font-family: 'Footlight MT Light', 'Garamond';
       font-size: 52px; color: #FF3B3F; font-weight: bold; margin: 0 }
h3 {font-family: 'Footlight MT Light', 'Garamond';
       font-size: 42px; color: #FF3B3F; font-weight: bold; margin: 0}
h4 {font-family: 'Footlight MT Light', 'Garamond';
       font-size: 32px; color: #FF3B3F; font-weight: bold; margin: 0}
h5 {font-family: 'Georgia', 'Garamond';
       font-size: 18px; color: #062f4f; font-weight: bold; margin: 0}
h6 {font-family: 'Georgia', 'Garamond';
       font-size: 18px; color: #062f4f; font-weight: bold; margin: 0}
p  {font-family: 'Georgia', 'Garamond';
       font-size: 18px; color: #062f4f; font-weight: none; margin: 0}

ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 10px;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: none;
}

li {
    float: right;

}

li a {
    display: block;
    color: #062f4f;
font-family: "Footlight MT Light";
font-size:28px;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

li a:hover {
    background-color: #FF3B3F;
    color: #ffffff;
}

#aboutus1{
  background-color:#CAEBF2;
  width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
}  

#aboutus2{
background-color:#EFEFEF;
  width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
}

.aboutus3{
background-color:#CAEBF2;
  width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
}

.aboutus3 h{
background-color:#CAEBF2;
  width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
}

.aboutus3 h1 {font-family: 'Footlight MT Light', 'Garamond';
       font-size: 100px; color: #062f4f; font-weight: bold; margin: 0 }

.aboutus3 h2 {font-family: 'Footlight MT Light', 'Garamond';
       font-size: 52px; color: #062f4f; font-weight: bold; margin: 0 }

.aboutus3 h3 {font-family: 'Footlight MT Light', 'Garamond';
       font-size: 42px; color: #FF3B3F; font-weight: bold; margin: 0}

.aboutus3 h4 {font-family: 'Footlight MT Light', 'Garamond';
       font-size: 32px; color: #FF3B3F; font-weight: bold; margin: 0}

.aboutus3 h5 {font-family: 'Georgia', 'Garamond';
font-size: 22px; color: #062f4f; font-weight: bold; margin: 0}

.aboutus3 h6 {font-family: 'Georgia', 'Garamond';
       font-size: 18px; color: #062f4f; font-weight: bold; margin: 0}

.aboutus3 p  {font-family: 'Georgia', 'Garamond';
       font-size: 18px; color: #062f4f; font-weight: none; margin: 0}

#aboutus4{
background-color:#EFEFEF;
  width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
}  

#aboutus5{
  width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
}

@media 
only screen and (max-width: 760px),
(min-device-width: 768px) and (max-device-width: 1024px)  {

    /* Force table to not be like tables anymore */
    table, thead, tbody, th, td, tr { 
        display: block; 
    }

    /* Hide table headers (but not display: none;, for accessibility) */
    thead tr { 
        position: absolute;
        top: -9999px;
        left: -9999px;
    }

    td { 
        /* Behave  like a "row" */
        border: none; 
        position: relative;
        padding-left: 37%; 
    }

    td:before { 
        /* Now like a table header */
        position: absolute;
        /* Top/left values mimic padding */
        top: 6px;           
        white-space: nowrap;
    }
}

.footer{
  width: 100%;
  height: 25vh;
  background-color: #ffffff;
}

.footer a {
    color: #FC4A1A;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.footer p {
font-size: 14px; padding: 2px; color: #062f4f;
}

#footercolumn1 {
float: left; margin: 0; width: 200px; padding: 15px 280px 0 5px;
}

#footercolumn2 {
float: left; margin: 0; width: 200px; padding: 15px 280px 0 0px;
}

#footercolumn3 {
float: left; margin: 0; width: 200px; padding: 15px 0px 0 0px;
}

button {
  -webkit-border-radius: 28;
  -moz-border-radius: 28;
  border-radius: 28px;
  font-family: Arial;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 12px;
  background: #062f4f;
  padding: 10px 20px 10px 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

button:hover {
  background: #FF3B3F;
  text-decoration: none;
}

 #ideascolumn {
 float: left; margin: 0; width: 48%; height: 300px; background-color:#CAEBF2; padding: 0 0 0 2%;
 }

  #casestudiescolumn {
float: left; margin: 0; width: 48%; height: 300px; background-color:#062f4f; padding: 0 0 0 2%;"
 }

#avatar1hover {
    padding: 0px;
    display: none;
text-align: center;
}

#pmhover:hover + #avatar1hover {
    display: block;
}

#avatar2hover {
    padding: 0px;
    display: none;
text-align: center;
}

#awhover:hover + #avatar2hover {
    display: block;
}

#avatar3hover {
    padding: 0px;
    display: none;
text-align: center;
}

#drhover:hover + #avatar3hover {
    display: block;
}

#avatar4hover {
    padding: 0px;
    display: none;
text-align: center;
}

#mdhover:hover + #avatar4hover {
    display: block;
}

#avatar5hover {
    padding: 0px;
    display: none;
text-align: left;
}

#rkhover:hover + #avatar5hover {
    display: block;
}

#avatar6hover {
    padding: 0px;
    display: none;
text-align: left;
}

#mwhover:hover + #avatar6hover {
    display: block;
}

#avatar7hover {
    padding: 0px;
    display: none;
text-align: left;
}

#lrhover:hover + #avatar7hover {
    display: block;
}

#avatar8hover {
    padding: 0px;
    display: none;
text-align: left;
}

#ahhover:hover + #avatar8hover {
    display: block;
}

span:hover + div {
display:block;
}


</style>

</head>
<body>
<div id="aboutus1">
  <a href="*"><img src="images/Logo1.png" alt="Budget Line of Business Logo"
  style="float:left;width:220px;height:237px;padding:10px 0px 0px 15px;"/></a>
  <ul><strong>
  <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
  <li><a href="#ideas">Ideas</a></li>
<li><a href="*">Our Work</a></li>
  <li><a href="*">About Us</a></li>
<li><a href="*">Home</a></li>
</strong>
</ul>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br><br><br>
<br>
<br>
<h1><center>Illuminators & Inventors</center></h1><br>
<h5 style="text-align: center; padding:0px 100px;">We're a creative team of problem-solving consultants bringing fresh ideas and innovation to budget communities across the federal government.<br>Find out what we can do for you.</h5>
<br><br>
<center><a href="*"><button>SEE OUR WORK</button></a></center>
<br><br>
</div>

<div id="aboutus2">
<br><br><br>
<div class="container"><center>
  <h3>What can we do for you?</h3>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-info" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#demo"><b>+</b></button>
  <div id="demo" class="collapse">
    <h5>
Onboarding<br>
Portals<br>
Workflows<br>
Data Collection<br>
Data Analytics<br>
Project Management<br>
Budget Trainings<br>
Career Development</center>
</h5>
  </div>
<br>

<div id="avatartable1">
  <table style="table-layout:fixed; width:100%">
    <tr>
 <td id="avatar4"><center>
<span id="staffmdhover"><img src="images/avatarmd.png" alt="The Mastermind Avatar"
  style="width:170px;height:150px"/></span>
<div id="avatar4hover"><p>I can connect you with an agency who is working through the exact same questions.</p></div>
      </center></td>
<td id="avatar1"><center>
<span id="pmhover"><img src="images/avatarpm.png" alt="The Mastermind Avatar"
  style="width:180px;height:150px"/></span>
<div id="avatar1hover"><p>I am building tools behind the scenes to make your life easier.</p></div>
      </center></td>
<td id="avatar2"><center>
<span id="awhover"><img src="images/avataraw.png" alt="The Mastermind Avatar"
  style="width:180px;height:150px"/></span>
<div id="avatar2hover"><p>I can help you become a MAX guru.</p></div>
      </center></td>
<td id="avatar3"><center>
<span id="drhover"><img src="images/avatardr.png" alt="The Mastermind Avatar"
  style="width:200px;height:150px"/></span>
<div id="avatar3hover"><p>I can help you build a workflow using Collect Forms.</p></div>
      </center></td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>

<br><br>

<div id="avatartable2">
<table style="table-layout:fixed; width:100%">
    <tr>
<td id="avatar5">
<span id="rkhover"><img src="images/avatarrk.png" alt="The Mastermind Avatar"
  style="width:200px;height:150px"/></span>
<div id="avatar5hover"><p>I can teach you how to master Excel.</p></div>
      </td>
<td id="avatar6">
<span id="mwhover"><img src="images/avatarmw.png" alt="The Mastermind Avatar"
  style="width:180px;height:150px"/></span>
<div id="avatar6hover"><p>I can brainstorm with you about how to streamline your budget processes.</p></div>
      </td>
<td id="avatar7">
<span id="lrhover"><img src="images/avatarlr.png" alt="The Mastermind Avatar"
  style="width:180px;height:150px"/></span>
<div id="avatar7hover"><p>I can point you in the direction of career development resources.</p></div>
<td id="avatar8">
<span id="ahhover"> <img src="images/avatarah.png" alt="The Mastermind Avatar"
  style="width:180px;height:150px"/></span>
<div id="avatar8hover"><p>I can help you create a one-stop shop budget portal for your office.</p></div>       
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>

<br><br>
</div>

<div class="aboutus3" style="color: #062f4f">
<br><br><br>
<center>
<h3>Our Vision</h3>
<h6 style="text-align: center; width: 60%;">Developing modern, adaptable, cost effective and optimized process, technology, and human capital solutions supporting all phases of the formulation and execution of the Federal Budget.</h6>
</center>
<br><br>
<div>

<table style="table-layout:fixed; width:100%">
    <tr>
<td id="goal1">
<center><img src="images/goal1.png" alt="Goal 1: Process Picture"
  style="width:425px;height:425px"/>
<h4 style="text-align: center;">Process</h4><br>
<p style="text-align: center; width: 450px;"><b>Goal 1:</b> Improve the efficiency and effectiveness of agency and central processes for forumulating and executing the Federal Budget.</p>
</center>
      </td>
<td id="goal2">
<center><img src="images/goal2.png" alt="Goal 2: Technology Picture"
  style="width:425px;height:425px"/>
<h4 style="text-align: center;">Technology</h4><br>
<p style="text-align: center;width: 450px;"><b>Goal 2:</b> Improve capabilities for analyzing and presenting budget, execution, planning, and financial information in support of decision making.</p></center>
      </td>
<td id="goal3">
<center><img src="images/goal3.png" alt="Goal 3: Human Capital Picture"
  style="width:425px;height:425px"/>
<h4 style="text-align: center;">Human Capital</h4><br>
<p style="text-align: center;width: 450px;"><b>Goal 3:</b> Enhance the effectiveness of the Federal budgeting workforce.</p></center>
</td>
    </tr>
  </table>

</div>
<br><br><br>
</div>

<div id="aboutus4">
<center>
<br><br><br>
<h3>Transforming budget offices since 2006</h3><br><br>
<img src="images/timeline.png" alt="Budget Line of Business Timeline"
  style="width: 1100px;height:850px"/>
<br><br>

</center>  
</div>

<div id="aboutus5">

<div id="ideascolumn">
<br><br><br><br>
<table style="table-layout:fixed; width:100%">
    <tr>
<td id="ideaspic" style="width:20%">
<img src="images/groupavatar.png" alt="Group of Avatars"
  style="width:150px;height:150px"/><br>
      </td>
<td id="ideasdescription" style="width:60%">
<h3 style="text-align: left; width: 80%;">Send us a challenge</h3></center>
<br><h6 style="text-align: left; width: 70%;">If you've got a specific business challenge, we’d love to help you tackle it. Please get in touch with us.</h6></center>
<br><h6 style="text-align: left; width: 70%;"><a href="mailto:*" style="color: #FF3B3F;font-size: 18px;font-weight: bold; text-decoration: none;">*</a></h6></center>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
<br><br><br>
</div>

<div id="casestudiescolumn">
<br><br><br><br>
<table style="table-layout:fixed; width:100%">
    <tr>
<td id="ideaspic" style="width:20%">
<img src="images/atwork.png" alt="At Work Graphic"
  style="width:150px;height:150px"/><br>
      </td>
<td id="ideasdescription" style="width:60%">
<h3 style="text-align: left; width: 90%;">View our work</h3></center>
<br><h6 style="text-align: left; width: 70%; color:white">Check out some of the cool things we're working on right now.</h6></center>
<br><a href="*"><button>SEE OUR WORK</button></a>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
</div>

<div class="footer">

<div id="footercolumn1">
<h5 style="color: #062f4f;">Sign up at MAX.gov</h5><br>
<p>Have a .gov email address?<br><br> Sign up for MAX.gov <a href="max.gov">here</a> and then email us to access all of our budget resources.</p>
</div>

<div id="footercolumn2">
<h5 style="color: #062f4f;">Send us your ideas</h5><br>
<p>If you have a specific challenge for us, fill out <a href="link to form page">this form</a> with all of your details.</p></div>

<div id="footercolumn3">
<h5 style="color: #062f4f;">Get in touch
</h5><br>
<p>*<p>
<a href="mailto:*">Text</a>
<br><br>
<div>
<a href="[full link to your Twitter]">
<img title="Twitter" alt="Twitter" src="https://socialmediawidgets.files.wordpress.com/2014/03/01_twitter1.png" width="35" height="35" />
</a>
<a href="[full link to your LinkedIn]">
<img title="LinkedIn" alt="LinkedIn" src="https://socialmediawidgets.files.wordpress.com/2014/03/07_linkedin1.png" width="35" height="35" />
</a>
<a href="[full link to your Facebook page]">
<img title="Facebook" alt="Facebook" src="https://socialmediawidgets.files.wordpress.com/2014/03/02_facebook1.png" width="35" height="35" />
</a>
<a href="pinterestaddress">
<img title="Pinterest" alt="Pinterest" src="https://socialmediawidgets.files.wordpress.com/2014/03/13_pinterest1.png" width="35" height="35" />
</a>
</div>
</div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you please simplify your code and remove any unnecessary HTML / CSS

Comment: You'll have better luck getting your question answered if you put up a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) of your code. That way you can include all of it in a constructive manner.

Comment: `I've added some script to my code and it's messing up formatting elsewhere in my doc` the code you posted has no javascript - it includes external javascript and css, so it's likely it's the CSS that's messing your page up - you can use the developer tools element inspector to see how the bootstrap css is interfering with your own css

Comment: A quick note on CSS: you can apply the same style to multiple selector by separating them with commas. Should shorten things quite a bit with headers 1-6.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's not a `JS` issue. It's because you're including `Bootstrap css` in

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
```

Which is conflicting with your own CSS. At a glance, I could see the property which is conflicting here is `box-sizing`

> > Standard solution:

Rewrite your custom CSS so it wouldn't conflict with the boostrap one.

> > Hack Solution (Not encouraged.. Just to show you where you're wrong):

Just include the following in your custom CSS

```
* {
    -webkit-box-sizing: inherit; 
    -moz-box-sizing: inherit;
    box-sizing: inherit;
}
```

Comment: Thank you!!! I intend on cleaning the whole thing up but right now I just need to demo the page and I really didn't want it to have the formatting issues so the hack you provided works brilliantly. Thank you so much!!